# Mapping to static pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to simply link to a static view in my `TodosController` in Rails. What's the correct way of doing this?

In `routes.rb`

I have `match '/about' => 'todos#about'`

which I would expect to link to `about.html.erb`

And in my controller I have

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
     ....
     def about
     end
end
```

I get this returned back to me: `Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/about"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
match '/about' => 'todos#about'
```

With

```
match '/about' => 'todos#about', via: [:get]
```

Assuming that you are using Rails 3, you need to specify the HTTP method.

For Rails 4, you can use

```
get "about", :to => "todos#about"
```

Comment: Aw shoot you beat me to it

Comment: @TMP No Problem. You can beat me next time. :)

Comment: I even had a typo in mine, I had to delete it out of shame